# iphone get both camera image for iphone 7 plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-camera

Can I get both images of regular and wide angle camera at the same time? What about videos, can I get video streams from both cameras?

Comment: i also want to do the same. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done but you can do it by View containers. Add 2 ViewController contener to the UIViewController and add UIImagePickerController in both containers.
In first Container make CameraMode to frontCamera and for second Container make cameraMode to BackCamera.

Hope it helps.